# Several Chart.js canvas in a div but only last one is dispayed

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I have several canvas in a page, each displaying a Chart.js chart. I define each chart as:

```
<div>
    <canvas id="chartId1" style="width:100% !important; height: 400px !important;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="chartId2" style="width:100% !important; height: 400px !important;"></canvas>
    
    <canvas id="chartIdn" style="width:100% !important; height: 400px !important;"></canvas>
</div>
```

and populate each in JavaScript (the following code is iterated in a for loop where I pass the canvas id):

```
var options1 = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [dates],
        datasets: [{
            label: currentNodeType + ' [ ' + currentNodeUnit + ' ]',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235, 0.3)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235, 0.3, 0.3)',
            data: [values],
            pointRadius: 5,
            hoverRadius: 6,
            borderWidth: 1,
            hitRadius: 10
        }]
    },
   options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                   reverse: false,
                   suggestedMin: 0
                }
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            display: true,
            labels: {
                fontSize: 18,
                boxWidth: 18
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            zoom: {
                 pan: {
                      enabled: true
                 },
                 zoom: {
                      enabled: true,
                      drag: true,
                      mode: 'xy',
                      speed: 0.1
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}

var ctxChart1 = document.getElementById('chartId1').getContext('2d');
var chart1 = new Chart(ctxChart1, options1);
```

When I open the page in a brwoser only the last canvas is visible and I see empty spaces in place of the others. However when I try to download an image of any invisible chart (I convert it  to Base64 as follows) the chart is perfectly fine. Why is it not visible in the page?

```
var dataURL = chart.toBase64Image();
var a = window.document.createElement('a');
a.href = dataURL;
a.download = fileName + '.png';
```

Comment: Without a minimal working example is kind of hart to tell. But make sure that they are not overlaid, and also be aware that even if the canvas thinks something has been resized it might disappear in some scenarios.

Comment: Can you add a reproducable fiddle of some kind since it seems to work just fine with your config: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/sa9wgtbL/2/